# How is structured clone algorithm different from deep copy

Tags: javascript

There's a [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) that states that:

> The structured clone algorithm is a new algorithm defined by the HTML5
>   specification for serializing complex JavaScript objects. It's more
>   capable than JSON

So, I believe this means that it's more capable than cloning in this way:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript). The JSON way has many drawbacks like not supporting circular references, dropping everything not supported by JSON spec, like functions, and representing Date object as strings.

I then thought that structured clone algorithm is deep copy algorithm implemented by many libraries. However, it's listed on the same page with the words:

> If you want a deep copy of an object (that is, a recursive copy of all
>   nested properties, walking the prototype chain), you must use another
>   approach. The following is a possible example.

So now I'm confused and don't know what is structured algorithm or how it's different from deep copy. Any help? I don't want to read a spec, maybe some libraries implemented it, so I can read their source code.

Comment: MDN can be edited by anyone. The deep cloning example has no place there.

Comment: @Ryan `If you don’t use code formatting for emphasis, we can probably be friends.` :) nice info

Answer (score 17):

**Structued Clone Algorithm** is one of the way to deep copy your `JavaScript object`. Since this api is not exposed directly so we have alternate ways by which we can use it.

**Why do we use it anyway if we have JSON.parse and JSON.stringify?**

> Because JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) has some limitations like you have mentioned, which are, they do not serialize the circular object or things like Map, Set, Date, RegEx etc.

So, this is where this api(**Structure clone**) comes into play.

**How to use it?**

> Since this api(Structured Cloning) is not directly exposed but it is used by some other apis. So we can use those other apis in order to use Structured Cloning.

Such apis are:

1. `history.pushState`
2. `MessageChannel`
3. `Notification`

To see the examples and comparison between these apis, I highly recommend **Surma** [blogpost](https://dassur.ma/things/deep-copy/).

---

**Update**

So, finally Structured Clone api is directly exposed in some of the browsers([see supported versions and coverage](https://caniuse.com/?search=structuredClone)) under the function name `structuredClone()`.

**How to use it?**

Example with date object:

```js
const a = { x: 20, date: new Date() };
const b = structuredClone(a); // { x: 20, date: <date object> }
```

*Note: with `JSON.stringify` the date object would have been serialized with `Date.prototype.toJSON`*

Example with circular object:

```js
const a = { x: 20, date: new Date() };
a.c = a;
const b = structuredClone(a); // { x: 20, date: <date object>, c: <circular ref> }
```

*Note: with `JSON.stringify` it will throw a TypeError*

Answer (score -1):

I know the question was asked years ago and barely had any activity but it's worth closing all unanswered questions.

In the same article, a note now appeared:

> This specification used to define a "structured clone" algorithm, and more recently a StructuredClone abstract operation. However, in practice all known uses of it were better served by separate serialization and deserialization steps, so it was removed.

Which means that the premise of the question no longer exist.

In short: there is no such thing as Structured Clone algorithm.

Comment: Actually, the algorithm still exists and is described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#structuredserialize).

Comment: Where exactly? That's where I'm quoting from, and the only StrucutredClone keyword is in the text I cited

Comment: @Adelin it does now